# Solr field for storing range

Tags: solr

Is there a solr field type that would work well storing a range of two values?

For example, I'm trying to store a min and max cost for each document i.e. $0 to $100, or $50 to $100

I'd then want to be able to query a single value to see if it falls in the range. i.e. which documents' range allows $25?

I realize a workaround would be to store min and max separately, but wondering if any native fields support this to simplify querying?

Comment: The simplest solution is the one below; but you can think of your min/max costs as a line - i.e. indexing it as a set of one dimensional points and then using the INTERSECTS operation. See [Spatial Search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/spatial-search.html#spatial-search) for more information - and it should work using the described RPT field type using WKT to describe the form.

Answer (score 1):

There is no field which stores data range as integer and providing results according to that data. You can have a look at Solr field [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/field-types-included-with-solr.html)

As you said you can keep min and max as separate fields and it will not make your query complicated. You only need to have `value < field_max && value > field_min`. this query in your solr query.

Comment: Will this work for situations where there are multiple ranges per document? In such a case, the desired behaviour is usually to check if one or more of the document ranges overlap with the query range. Keeping the fields separate might lead to the situation where the overlap is checked against a single range spanning from the minimum value of field_min to the maximum value of field_max.